# Take Dialogflow intent and query Firestore

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es

My chatbot has been created in Dialogflow and I am now trying to access it from Python, to take user inputs and display outputs in the GUI (think a basic chatbot gui).

I have connected my Python environment to Dialogflow and to firestore,

Here is the code that detects intents;

```
#Detection of Dialogflow intents, project and input.
def detect_intent_texts(project_id, session_id, texts, language_code):
   #Returns the result of detect intent with texts as inputs, later can implement same `session_id` between requests allows continuation of the conversaion.
    import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

    session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
#To ensure session path is correct - print('Session path: {}\n'.format(session))

    for text in texts:
        text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text=text, language_code=language_code)
        query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
        response = session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)

        print ('Chatbot:{}\n'.format(response.query_result.fulfillment_text))
detect_intent_texts("chat-8","abc",["Hey"],"en-us")
```

I need to somehow say if THIS intent is triggered, get something from the db and display to user.

**UPDATE**

My current code in full, everything is looking right to me but it's throwing an error I don't understand, thanks to Sid8491 for the help so far.

in short, my issue is, my previous code allowed me to type something and the chatbot respond, it was all in the console but it worked... The new code is supposed to allow me to say "When THIS intent is triggered, do THIS"

```
import os, json
import sys
import dialogflow
from dialogflow_v2beta1 import *
import firebase_admin
import requests.packages.urllib3
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
from firebase_admin import firestore
from firebase_admin import credentials
import requests.packages.urllib3
from Tkinter import *
from dialogflow_v2beta1 import agents_client
import Tkinter as tk
result = None
window = Tk()

def Response():
    #no need to use global here
    result = myText.get()
    displayText.configure(state='normal')
    displayText.insert(END, "User:"+ result + '\n')
    displayText.configure(state='disabled')

#Creating the GUI
myText = tk.StringVar()
window.resizable(False, False)
window.title("Chatbot")
window.geometry('400x400')
User_Input = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=myText, width=50).place(x=20, y=350)
subButton = tk.Button(window, text="Send", command=Response).place(x =350, y=350)
displayText = Text(window, height=20, width=40)
displayText.pack()
scroll = Scrollbar(window, command=displayText).pack(side=RIGHT)
window.mainloop()

#Initialize the firebase admin SDK
cred = credentials.Certificate('./file.json')
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()

def getCourse():
    doc_ref = db.collection(u"Course_Information").document(u"CourseTypes")
    try:
        doc = doc_ref.get()
        return 'Document data: {}'.format(doc.to_dict())
    except google.cloud.exceptions.NotFound:
        return 'Not found'

def detect_intent_text(project_id, session_id, text, language_code):
    GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=".chat-8.json"
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)

    session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)

    text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(
        text=text, language_code=language_code)

    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)

    response = session_client.detect_intent(
        session=session, query_input=query_input)

queryText = [myText.get()]

res = detect_intent_text('chat-8', 'session-test', queryText, 'en')
intentName = res['query_result']['intent']['display_name']

if intentName == 'CourseEnquiry':
    reponse = getCourse()
    print json.dumps({
        'fulfillmentText': reponse,
    })
elif intentName == 'Greetings':
    print "Yo"

detect_intent_texts("chat-8","abc", queryText,"en-us")
```

But I get this error:

```
C:\Users\chat\PycharmProjects\Chatbot\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/chat/PycharmProjects/Chatbot/venv/Chatbot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/chat/PycharmProjects/Chatbot/venv/Chatbot.py", line 65, in <module>
    res = detect_intent_text('chat-8', 'session-test', queryText, 'en')
  File "C:/Users/chat/PycharmProjects/Chatbot/venv/Chatbot.py", line 51, in detect_intent_text
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)
  File "C:\Users\chat\PycharmProjects\Chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\dialogflow_v2\gapic\sessions_client.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.sessions_stub = (session_pb2.SessionsStub(channel))
  File "C:\Users\chat\PycharmProjects\Chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\dialogflow_v2\proto\session_pb2.py", line 1248, in __init__
    self.DetectIntent = channel.unary_unary(
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'unary_unary'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Here is a sample in Node.js doing what you're trying to do: https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-firestore-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think you are on the right track.

You need to extract `intentName` or `actionaName` from the response you got from the `dialogFlow` and call your corresponding functions and then send the response back to user.

```
res = detect_intent_texts("chat-8","abc",["Hey"],"en-us")
action = res['queryResult']['action']

if action == 'getSomethingFromDb':
    reponse = someFunction(req)
    return json.dumps({
        'fulfillmentText': reponse,
    })
elif action == 'somethingElse':
    ....
```

If you want it to do using `intentName` instead of `actionName` then you can extract `intentName` like below

```
intentName = res['query_result']['intent']['display_name']
```

EDIT 1:
Example -

```
import dialogflow
import os, json

def getCourse():
    doc_ref = db.collection(u"Course_Information").document(u"CourseTypes")
    try:
        doc = doc_ref.get()
        return 'Document data: {}'.format(doc.to_dict())
    except google.cloud.exceptions.NotFound:
        return 'Not found'

def detect_intent_text(project_id, session_id, text, language_code):
    GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\\pyth_to_...\\cred.json"
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)

    session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)

    text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(
        text=text, language_code=language_code)

    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)

    response = session_client.detect_intent(
        session=session, query_input=query_input)

queryText = 'get courses of Python' # you will call some function to get text from your app

res = detect_intent_text('project_1234', 'session-test', queryText, 'en')
intentName = res['query_result']['intent']['display_name']

if intentName == 'getCourse':
    reponse = getCourse()
    return json.dumps({
        'fulfillmentText': reponse,
    })
```

Try above example and change according to your needs of app. My suggestion is to first get DialogFlow working without app, then integrate it with the app. Otherwise you won't be able to understand whether problem is happening in DialogFlow or your app.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @sid8491, I will give that a go and see what I get.

Comment: I'd rather extract intentName, where you have wrote someFunction, is that where I'd write a function with the db query code in (for example, my def GetCourse(session_client) like in the question? thank you

Comment: yep, your understanding is correct. and when you get response, transform it into human readable format and dump it into `fulfillmentText`. let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you @sid8491, I'll type up what I think and let you know with and further questions and accept if all goes well. Thank you again.

Comment: Thanks @sid8491 I have updated the question with what I think I need to do, I may have misinterpreted your example wrong as it's showing an error.

Comment: Hey @sid8491, still getting nowhere with this unfortunately, error says return outside of function, I have tried moving code around and making sure indents are correct but nothing seems to want to work, any advice?

Comment: you need to post your complete code, i guess error is in getCourse() function. i will post an example so clarify things.

Comment: you need to post your complete code, i guess error is in getCourse() function. i will post an example so clarify things.

Comment: Full code is now in question, you will note two problems (one which is another question I asked about displaying user input in tk.Text)

the code you helped with is at the very bottom

Comment: Thanks @sid8491, Dialogflow is 100% working both on their website and in my code (I get the response I want in the console). I'll implement now and let you know, many thanks again

Comment: Okay @sid8491, implemented exactly and changed the details, getting one error saying "Invalid Syntax"
`return 'Document data: {}'.format(doc.to_dict())`
On that line, pointing towards the return statement.

The bottom `if intentName` statement is still highlighting as "return out of function" for some reason. Strange, Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: i made mistake in indentation in return statements. try now.

Comment: Thank you @sid8491, getting there slowly, this part:
`if intentName == 'getCourse':
    reponse = getCourse()
    return json.dumps({
        'fulfillmentText': reponse,
    })`
Is showing "return outside function" still. the last 3 lines are red underlined.

Comment: but the first part is no longer showing an error so that's good. 
Wouldn't the query part just be my def getCourse function? Considering that has the database query in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177271/discussion-between-sid8491-and-tipping44).